# How to hide section in tableView after deleting last item?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

When I delete the last item in section , footer in this section is visible. How I can hide it?
I using for deleting  `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`, not `tableView.reloadData()`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        guard let section = ComistType.init(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return }

        taskList[section]?.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        if taskList[section]?.count == 0 {
            taskList.removeValue(forKey: section)

        }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uatOY.png)

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view
>   after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained
>   in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of
>   sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 2 deleted).'

Comment: Have you tried using `tableView.deleteSections()` when required, so that there is no 'empty section' left?

Comment: I have an error. Look at stack trace upper

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Shaw proposed, you can use `deleteSections(_:with:)` function of `UITableView`.

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
    guard let section = ComistType.init(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return }

    taskList[section]?.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    if taskList[section]?.count == 0 {
        taskList.removeValue(forKey: section)

        // This line does the magic
        tableView.deleteSections([section], with: .fade)
    }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Check the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614922-deletesections) for more details.

**UPDATE**

Don't forget to reflect total number of sections in your tableview datasource
using `numberOfSections(in:)` delegate function.

Comment: I know about this method, but when I call it - have an error. Look at question, I have added error stack trace

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to return correct number of sections in numberOfSections(in:) delegate method

Answer (score 0):

After you delete your section, your `numberOfRowsInSection` method is returning the wrong value for the other sections.

Say you have three sections: `ComistType(rawValue: 0)`, `ComistType(rawValue: 1)`, `ComistType(rawValue: 2)`. Then if you delete section with `ComistType(rawValue: 1)` then your dictionary now has two keys: `ComistType(rawValue: 0)` and `ComistType(rawValue: 2)`. What it should have is `ComistType(rawValue: 0)` and `ComistType(rawValue: 1)` in order for the table view to work correctly after the deletion.

It is much better to use an array of arrays so you don't have to update all of your keys.

Try this:

```
var taskList: [[Int]] = [[1, 2], [4, 5]]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return taskList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return taskList[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }

    taskList[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.item)
    if taskList[indexPath.section].count == 0 {
        taskList.remove(at: indexPath.section)
        tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .fade)
    } else {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```